# Unexpected Result with Cpp Vector insert

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following function

```
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int original_size = nums.size();
        k = k%original_size;
        nums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.end()-k, nums.end());
        nums.resize(original_size);
    }
```

For these inputs, I get the proper result

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
3
----
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

============
[-1]
2
----
[-1]
```

However, for the input below, I am getting the wrong result.

```
[1,2,3]
1
----
[2,1,2]
```

It seems that the `nums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.end()-k, nums.end());` properly works on the first two example, but not on the third one. I can't think of why is that.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: `insert` can invalidate iterators and references to elements in the vector. I'm not sure it is possible to use `insert` to move around elements of a vector safely as the iterators provided to do so may become invalidated during the process.

Comment: I was hoping to have something like `O(1)` is there a way to change the underlaying vector data manually?

Comment: I think you are looking for a circular buffer. There is no standard container for that, there are only adapters which won't be sufficient for your needs. `std::rotate` on a `std::vector` of simple types like `int` is pretty quick though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not use `insert` with `first` and `last` being iterators to the same vector. That is because inserting elements invalidates iterators. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) (overload 4):

> The behavior is undefined if `first` and `last` are iterators into `*this`.

You can use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to rotate elements in a vector.